# How to show css div depending upon model value?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on mvc4 project

I have following code html :

```
<div class="rating">Rating</div> <div class="ratingpoint" title="rating">
<span class="font-icon-star"></span> 
<span class="font-icon-star"></span> 
<span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
</div>
```

It will show css `stars` like below image.

But i want this to be dynamic depending upon my `Model.rating values`

I tried like following

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MYTABLE)
{ 
  <div class="rating">Rating</div> <div class="ratingpoint" title="rating">
@if(@item.rating == 2){
    <span class="font-icon-star"></span> 
    <span class="font-icon-star"></span> 
}//but how to show the full stars ans below empty stars ?
    <span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
    <span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
    <span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
    </div> 
}
```

see image attached example 2 fulled stars and 3 empty
[image]

> If I have rating value as 4 then i want to show 4 full stars and 1 empty star

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@for (int i=0; i < item.rating; i++) 
{ 
    <span class="font-icon-star"/> 
}
@for (int i=item.rating; i < 5; i++) 
{ 
    <span class="font-icon-star-line"/> 
}
```

or you can do something like

```
@for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    if (i < item.rating)
    {
        <span class="font-icon-star"/> 
    }
    else
    {
        <span class="font-icon-star-line"/> 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put a conditional in the class.  I am not sure all of the checks you have.  If you have multiple you can combine them like this

```
<span class="@(Model.rating == 2 ? "font-icon-star" : Model.rating == 4 ? "font-icon-star-line" : "")"></span>
```

Comment: no i can't do hardcore if my rating is 4 then? i need to show full 4 stars and 1 empty star

Comment: you can do multiple checks like my edit above or you can put ranges in there.  something like Model.rating > 2

Comment: not that I am aware of,  this is the way that we do conditional classes in our project